# JSP custom tag cannot complie

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, websphere, custom-tag

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <html:form>
        <custom:pagecontrol>
                //TODO
        </custom:pagecontrol>
    </html:form>
  </body></html>
```

I have a custom tag in jsp file. When run with Web Server of IBM in Eclipse, jsp file will fail to complie with message:

com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0049E: /jsp/abc.jsp failed to compile : C:\DEVELOPMENT\workspace.metadata.plugins\com.ibm.etools.wdt.server.core\tmp0\usr\servers\defaultServer0\workarea\org.eclipse.osgi\64\data\temp\default_node\SMF_WebContainer\com\ibm\ws\jsp\tagfile\webinf_pagecontrol.java : 52 : The type java.util.Map$Entry cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

When I comment out custom tag, jsp file still fail to compile.
When I delete custom tag, jsp file will success to compile.
I try to close/re-open eclipse, remove/reinstall web server it still fail to complie

Comment: You need to add to the question code that implements your tag and where you put it.

Comment: @Gas Sorry for mistake. I added code structure.

Comment: Are you sure the tag class itself has no errors?

Comment: @nitind I tried to delete all code in custom tag, but can not resolve